# How to get a value from resource file using its key

Tags: c#

How to get a value from resource file using its key

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[ResourceManager.GetString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.getstring.aspx) or [ResourceManager.GetStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxee5096.aspx), depending on the type of the resource.

Answer (score 9):

```
public string ReadResourceValue(string file, string key)

{

    string resourceValue = string.Empty;
    try
    {

        string resourceFile = file;

        string filePath = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString();

        ResourceManager resourceManager = ResourceManager.CreateFileBasedResourceManager(resourceFile, filePath, null);
        // retrieve the value of the specified key
        resourceValue = resourceManager.GetString(key);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        resourceValue = string.Empty;
    }
    return resourceValue;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a much easier way: Namespace.Properties.Resources.FileName -> gets the string of the file-content.

i.e.: TestProject1.Properties.Resources.MyXmlFile -> direct access to the File in the resources

Answer (score -2):

In .cs file type your localization namespace:

```
   Localization.Resources.KeyName
```

Easy and fast :)

Comment: Where you get Localization object ?

Answer (score -3):

You can get `keyvalue` from `global resource` here.

```
//TestResource is resource class name.

String keyValue=string.Empty;

keyValue= Resources.TestResource.KeyString;
```