# Access Resource File Content in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net

I have a HTML file in the Resource1.resx. Now, i have to use the html file content by `StreamReader`. What should I do?

Following is the content of html file:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>$$name$$</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>$$subject$$</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

I am using the following code in the cs:

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
string resourceName = (string)GetGlobalResourceObject("Resource1", "MyTemplate");

using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    string readfile = reader.ReadToEnd();
    string mystring = "";
    mystring = readfile;
    mystring = mystring.Replace("$$Member$$", name);
    mystring = mystring.Replace("$$Subject$$", TxtSubject.Text);
    return mystring;
}
```

But `stream` returns `null`.

Comment: I think you should consider using UserControls if you really holding a html in a resource file. Mow its time to move away from such a new concept. Checkout http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1739/User-controls-in-ASP-NET. This quiet old, but will give ideo of its working

Comment: @AmitRanjan Well thanks for reply. But i have to use it by this way only because this is the requirement. If you have answer of this then help me otherwise thanks.

Comment: please follow this link.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946539/how-to-get-a-value-from-resource-file-using-its-key

Comment: @qamar I followed your link and after using I am getting null value from stream. I've also edited my code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Thanks to all to help me, but I found the solution. Here is the code:

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
string resourceName = (string)HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("Resource1", "MyTemplate");
string mystring = "";
mystring = resourceName;
mystring = mystring.Replace("$$Member$$", name);
mystring = mystring.Replace("$$Subject$$", TxtSubject.Text);
return mystring;
```