# Set BackgroundImage from string and Properties.Resources?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Windows Form with a `Button` control called `ButtonSelector`. I have a string variable `colorBg` that currently stores the value *Yellow*. `Properties.Resources` has an entry for an image file that's also called *Yellow*.

How can I set `ButtonSelector.BackgroundImage` to `MyApp.Properties.Resources.Yellow` using the value from my variable `colorBg`?

I'm currently using `switch-case`:

```
string colorBg = "Yellow";
switch (colorBg)
{
    case "Yellow":
        buttonSelector.BackgroundImage = MyApp.Properties.Resources.yellow;
        break;
    case "Blue":
        buttonSelector.BackgroundImage = MyApp.Properties.Resources.blue;
        break;
    case "Green":
        buttonSelector.BackgroundImage = MyApp.Properties.Resources.green;
        break;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a value from resource file using its key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946539/how-to-get-a-value-from-resource-file-using-its-key)

Answer (score 0):

rbhatup,

ButtonSelector.BackgroundImage = MyApp.Properties.Resources.GetObject(colorbg);

that will work if all the stars are aligned. The stars being:

1. colorbg contains a value which is actually in your resources
2. That resource item is an image which can be rendered.

In production, I would have a try catch around this and more robust testing of the value of colorbg etc.

Comment: `Properties.Resources` doesn't have a method called `GetObject`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using something like this:

```
ResourceManager rm = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager;
Bitmap myImage = (Bitmap)rm.GetObject(color);
buttonSelector.BackgroundImage = myImage;
```